# SQL Server Query that returns the number of Likes and number of Dislikes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL server table that displays what a user Liked or Disliked in an item description. He/she can only like/dislike one item so it will display a 1 if Liked or 0 if Disliked on the Type Field.

What I want is for an output that counts the Likes and Dislikes that displays both of them as seen below. I tried to do inner joins and unions and can't get it to work. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ItemID,
       Description,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Like,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Dislike
FROM Table
GROUP BY ItemID,
         Description
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
select ItemId,Description, sum(case when Type=1 then 1 else 0 end) 'like', // quote the word like
  sum(case when Type = 0 then 1 else 0 end) 'dislike'
from tblFeedback
group by ItemId
```